# How can access property from JSON file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, properties

I have a JSON file

Testing.json

```
{
  "DEV_MODE": false
}
```

and how can I access this value in JavaScript because i want to make check

if( DEV_MODE === true) {...} else {...}

I tried like this

```
import jsonFile from '../../testing.json'
var json = JSON.parse(jsonFile)
if(json.getProperty('DEV_MODE'){
...
}else{
...
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `if(json["DEV_MODE"]) {...`

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to access the `DEV_MODE` property like this:

`json.DEV_MODE` or `json["DEV_MODE"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can access to your json file easily and you don't need to parse that, like the following:

```
import jsonFile from '../../testing.json'
if (jsonFile.DEV_MODE) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```